# How to fix the int error in a matching game using python?

Tags: python, int

Okay, I've been trying this forever now. Keep getting stuck on a 'int' error.

Description:

A common memory matching game played by young children is to start with a deck of cards that contains identical pairs. For example, given six cards in the deck, two might be labeled 1, two labeled 2 and two labeled 3. The cards are shuffled and placed face down on a board. A player then selects two cards that are face down, turns them face up, and if the cards match they are left face up. If the two cards do not match, they  are returned to their original face down position. The game continues until all cards are face up.

Sample input/output:

> > > main()

You input number of rows and columns...
Enter number of rows: 3

Enter number of columns: 2

```
* *
* *
* *
```

Then you input coords like so...

Enter coordinates for first card: 1 1

Enter coordinates for second card: 3 1

Not an identical pair. Found 2 at (1,1) and 1 at (3,1)

```
* *
* *
* *
```

Enter coordinates for first card: 1 2

Enter coordinates for second card: 2 2

Not an identical pair. Found 2 at (1,2) and 3 at (2,2)

```
* *
* *
* *
```

Enter coordinates for first card: 1 1

Enter coordinates for second card: 1 2

```
2 2
* *
* *
```

Enter coordinates for first card: 3 1

Enter coordinates for second card: 3 2

Not an identical pair. Found 1 at (3,1) and 3 at (3,2)

```
2 2
* *
* *
```

Enter coordinates for first card: 2 1

Enter coordinates for second card: 3 1

```
2 2
1 *
1 *
```

Enter coordinates for first card: 3 2

Enter coordinates for second card: 2 2

```
2 2
1 3
1 3
```

> > > 

Requirements:

Design Requirments: You need to use three classes: Card, Deck and Game. Card stores both the card's value and face (a string or Boolean variable to indicate whether the card is facing up or down). Deck contains the cards needed for the game. It will contain among its methods a method to deal a card, another for shuffling the deck, and a method that returns number of cards left in the deck. These two classes are not identical to the classes Card and Deck discussed in the book but have many things in common. The class Game simulates playing a single game and represents the interaction between the user and the other classes. Its instance members store a 2D list (of card objects) representing the game board where the cards are placed, number of rows and number of columns of the game board. Among the instance methods of the Game class:  play(), which simulates playing the game; isGameOver(), which checks whether or not the game is over; displayBoard(), which displays the board; populateBoard(), which creates the initial 2D list of identical pairs of cards with all the cards facing down. Most probably, you will need to write other instance methods as you see appropriate.

My code so far:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    '''A card object with a suit and face'''

    def __init__(self, value):
        '''Stores both the card's value and face'''   
        self._value = value
        self._face = False

    def getValue(self):
        '''Get the value of the card'''
        return self._value

    def getFace(self):
        '''Get the face of the card'''
        return self._face
    def setFace(self):
        self._face = True

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, pairs):
        self._pairs = pairs
        self._cards = []
        for cards in range(self._pairs):
            c1 = Card(cards)
            self._cards.append(c1)
            c2 = Card(cards)
            self._cards.append(c2)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
           return None
        else:
           return self._cards.pop(0)

    def shuffle(self):
        '''Shuffels the cards.'''
        random.shuffle(self._cards)

    def __len__(self):
        '''Returns the number of cards in the deck'''
        return len(self._cards)

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self._deck = Deck((rows * columns)//2)
        self._rows = rows
        self._columns = columns
        self._board = []
        for row in range(self._rows):
            self._board.append([0] * columns)

    def populateBoard(self):
        self._deck_shuffle()
        for columns in self._columns:
            for rows in self._rows:
                self._board[rows][columns] = self._deck_deal()

    def displayBoard(self):
        for rows in self._rows:
            for columns in self._columns:
                if self._board[rows][columns]._getFace() == False:
                    print('*')
                else:
                    print(self._board[rows][columns._getValue()])
                print()

    def play(self):
        while True:
            if self.isGameOver() == False:
                break
            self.displayBoard()              
            coord1 = input('Enter coordinates for the first card: ')
            coord2 = input('Enter coordinates for the second card: ')
            newCoord1 = coord1.split(" ")
            newCard1 = self._board[int(newCoord1[0])][int(newCoord1[1])].getValue()
            newCoord2 = coord2.split(" ")
            newCard2 = self._board[int(newCoord2[0])][int(newCoord2[1])].getValue()
            if newCard1 != newCard2:
                print("Not an identical pair. Found", newCard1, "at", newCoord1, "and", newcard2, "at", newCoord2)
            else:
                self._board[int(newCoord1[0])][int(newCoord1[1])].setFace()
                self._board[int(newCoord2[0])][int(newCoord2[1])].setFace()

    def isGameOver(self):             
        face = False
        for rows in self._rows:
            for columns in self._columns:
                if self._board[row][column] == False:
                    face = True
        return face

def main():

    while True:
        # Force user to enter valid value for number of rows
        while True:
            rows = input("Enter number of rows ")
            if rows.isdigit() and ( 1 <= int(rows) <= 9):
                rows = int(rows)
                break
            else:
                print ("    ***Number of rows must be between 1 and 9! Try again.***")
                # Adding *** and indenting error message makes it easier for the user to see

        # Force user to enter valid value for number of columns
        while True:
            columns = input("Enter number of columns ")
            if columns.isdigit() and ( 1 <= int(columns) <= 9):
                columns = int(columns)
                break
            else:
                print ("    ***Number of columns must be between 1 and 9! Try again.***")

        if rows * columns % 2 == 0:
            break
        else:
            print ("    ***The value of rows X columns must be even. Try again.***")

    game = Game(rows, columns)
    game.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sorry for the format Problems. This site confuses me with it. Lol. If anyone can help me out, that'd be great.

EXACT TRACEBACKS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 135, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 132, in main
    game.play()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 84, in play
    self.displayBoard()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 74, in displayBoard
    if self._board[rows][columns].getFace() == False:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getFace'
```

and sometimes this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 127, in main
    game.play()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 79, in play
    self.displayBoard()
  File "C:\Users\River\Desktop\Hw-3.py", line 67, in displayBoard
    for rows in self._rows:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Maybe a **str** method? Not sure. If it is, not sure how to write one for this..

Comment: Show us the exact traceback, please.

Comment: your question needs to be more specific, currently you have listed the whole problem and all your code. Please update your question with the specifc problem you are having and an example of input and output

Comment: Better? Tried my best to clarify everything.

Comment: Your code needs to be almost completely rewritten! What you have right now tries to divide strings in half, try to call upon non-existant variables, and you mistake integers for objects. Lastly, what python version are you using?

Comment: Oh god... How would I rewrite this?.. And Python 3.4.

Comment: BTW: The second error happens because you can't iterate over a int line `for i in int:`, you need `for i in range(int):`. Note: **Never** name a variable `int`

Comment: Would be nice if we could Skype over this. Or have this be a Live Document like Google Drive,

Comment: I literally spent like 5 hours on this. Now I'm so tired..

Comment: You **never** call `populateBoard`.  So `self._board` remains a list of list of `int`s (all the `int`s are set at `0` in `Game.__init__`).  This explains the first of the two tracebacks, and @jakekimds has already explained the second one.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to do all these getters and setters like `def setValue(self, v): self._value = v`. There's not really private instance data in Python like in other languages. Just use the values directly.

Comment: Alex, Where would I call PopulateBoard at then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed most of your problems. See comments within. Your code is not considered "Pythonic", but I've left most of it as it is.

Your choice of variable and method names can be improved.
For e.g., when iterating over the rows and columns of the board, use `row` and `col` for the iterating variables.

Also, the `getFace()` method in `Card` class can perhaps be better renamed as `isFaceUp()`, or something to that effect. In this case, doing away with comparison with `False` will also read more naturally.

Another issue is your use of setters/getters. They are not considered "Pythonic" as others have already suggested in the comments.

With errors in different methods, some elementary, it seems that you were trying to write everything at one shot. It is often a good idea to write/test/debug small pieces of code at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function  # I'm using Python 2.7 so need this

import random


class Card(object):
    '''A card object with a suit and face'''

    def __init__(self, value):
        '''Stores both the card's value and face'''
        self._value = value
        self._face = False

    # Getters and setters are not Pythonic
    # Consider using property
    def getValue(self):
        '''Get the value of the card'''
        return self._value

    def getFace(self):
        '''Get the face of the card'''
        return self._face

    def setFace(self):
        self._face = True

    def __str__(self):
        '''Override str to return printable result. Useful for debugging.'''
        return ", ".join(("Value: ", str(self._value), "Face: ", str(self._face)))


class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, pairs):
        self._pairs = pairs
        self._cards = []
        for cards in range(self._pairs):
            c1 = Card(cards)
            self._cards.append(c1)
            c2 = Card(cards)
            self._cards.append(c2)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
           return None
        else:
           return self._cards.pop(0)

    def shuffle(self):
        '''Shuffles the cards.'''
        random.shuffle(self._cards)

    def __len__(self):
        '''Returns the number of cards in the deck'''
        return len(self._cards)


class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self._deck = Deck((rows * columns)//2)
        self._rows = rows
        self._columns = columns
        self._board = []
        for row in range(self._rows):
            self._board.append([0] * self._columns)

        self.populateBoard()
        # self.revealBoard()  # For debugging


    def populateBoard(self):
        self._deck.shuffle()
        # For debugging
        # print("Deck: {}".format(map(str, self._deck._cards)))
        # self._board = [[self._deck.deal() for _ in range(self._columns)]
        #                for _ in range(self._rows)]

        # Consider renaming variables as col and row. Similar for others
        # elsewhere
        for columns in range(self._columns):
            for rows in range(self._rows):
                self._board[rows][columns] = self._deck.deal()


    def revealBoard(self):
        """For debugging. Reveal the cards for the board"""
        for rows in range(self._rows):
            for columns in range(self._columns):
                print(str(self._board[rows][columns].getValue()) + " ", end="")

            print("")


    def displayBoard(self):
        for rows in range(self._rows):
            for columns in range(self._columns):
                if self._board[rows][columns].getFace() == False:
                    print('* ', end="")
                else:
                    # print(self._board[rows][columns._getValue()])
                    print(str(self._board[rows][columns].getValue()) + " ", end="")

            print("")  # Print newline after each row


    def play(self):
        while not self.isGameOver():
            self.displayBoard()
            coord1 = raw_input('Enter coordinates for the first card: ')
            coord2 = raw_input('Enter coordinates for the second card: ')
            newCoord1 = map(int, coord1.strip().split())
            newCard1 = self._board[newCoord1[0]][newCoord1[1]].getValue()
            newCoord2 = map(int, coord2.strip().split())
            newCard2 = self._board[newCoord2[0]][newCoord2[1]].getValue()

            # Need to check that user has entered valid data here

            # newCoord1 = coord1.split(" ")
            # newCard1 = self._board[int(newCoord1[0])][int(newCoord1[1])].getValue()
            # newCoord2 = coord2.split(" ")
            # newCard2 = self._board[int(newCoord2[0])][int(newCoord2[1])].getValue()
            if newCard1 != newCard2:
                print("Not an identical pair. Found", newCard1, "at", newCoord1, "and", newCard2, "at", newCoord2)
            else:
                self._board[newCoord1[0]][newCoord1[1]].setFace()
                self._board[newCoord2[0]][newCoord2[1]].setFace()
                # self._board[int(newCoord1[0])][int(newCoord1[1])].setFace()
                # self._board[int(newCoord2[0])][int(newCoord2[1])].setFace()

        print("Game Over")
        self.displayBoard()

    def isGameOver(self):
        for rows in range(self._rows):
            if not all(card.getFace() for card in self._board[rows]):
                return False
            # for columns in range(self._columns):
            #     # If there is still one card facing down then
            #     # game is not over yet
            #     if self._board[rows][columns].getFace() == False:
            #         return False
        return True


def getUserInput(input_type):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(raw_input("Enter number of {}: ".format(input_type)))
            if 1 <= val <= 9:
                return val
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print ("    ***Number of {} must be between 1 and 9! Try again.***".format(input_type))


def main():

    while True:
        # Force user to enter valid value for number of rows and columns
        rows = getUserInput("rows")
        columns = getUserInput("cols")

        if rows * columns % 2 == 0:
            break
        else:
            print ("    ***The value of rows X columns must be even. Try again.***")

    game = Game(rows, columns)
    game.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```